# How to set the classpath for the jvm that lein uses

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I want to create a new lein project from a template I have created without installing the template in .m2 or on clojars. So I want to set the classpath that lein uses when it works. How is this done?

Comment: any reason for not `installing the template in .m2` ? Otherwise maybe with `CLASSPATH=... lein new <your template> projectname` ?

Comment: just an intellectual exercise to see how to do it without

Comment: if you open your lein launcher (/usr/bin/lein or whatever) there is a code to honor CLASSPATH env vars (it prepends it); haven't tried it though